# Auto Define a sheet name

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to auto-define a sheet name in VBA.

This is the code I've created:

```
Range("F7:F11").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("janeiro").Select
Range("F7").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Basically, I need the contents in cell b2 to define the name of the sheet. On this example, the actual name of of the sheet is "janeiro", but I need the name to be defined by the contents of cell b2.

For example, `February, March...` done in an automatic way.

Is this possible?

Comment: There are some gotchas with naming sheets. I wrote a [blog post](http://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2013/10/25/dynamically-naming-excel-worksheets-the-headache-free-way/) about it you might find interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Replace "janeiro" with `Range("B2").Value`.

Then, tighten up your code a bit to [avoid using `Select` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select):

```
Range("F7:F11").Copy
Sheets(Range("B2").Value).Range("F7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Note: this will raise an error if the specified sheetname doesn't exist.

OR... this would be a great opportunity to show you how to use *variables*, rather than explicit references:

```
Dim shName as String 'Defines a STRING variable which we will use to hold a sheet name

shName = Range("B2").Value

'## Now, we can simply refer to shName any time we need to refer to the value in "B2"

Range("F7:F11").Copy
Sheets(shName).Value).Range("F7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```